# three.js rolling a camera on its side

Tags: camera, three.js, rotation, media-player, virtual-reality

I am working with a VR player, and I am loading videos in a non-standart format: they are side by side but on a vertical orientation. So to be able to view them on the right direction I am thinking of rolling the camera image. I have tried camera rotation with no luck. Is there other way to rotate the video itself with three.js?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the code that you tried to rotate the image to your post (use 4 spaces or tab indent for each line to format it like code)

Comment: What kind of video is it? a panoramic video? 180degrees? And where do you play the video? Projected on a Sphere? Or a plane?